# Writing a scheduled task (ConsoleApp) to write textfiles

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I need to write a task which writes Text into a Textfile. This shouldn´t be too complicated is what i first thought but i making a mistake somewhere pretty early. The Task should later run as a User which has no local Windows-Account, maybe that can be a problem, too, but im stuck even earlier. Im using me (local admin, domain user) to implement and run the task in windows task scheduler, the action is to run the .exe, task shall run even when not logged in.

The Code in the exe states as follws

```
    StreamWriter sw = null;
    try
    {
        sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\temp\test.txt");
        sw.WriteLine("something something");
    }
    finally { sw.Dispose(); }
```

The (temp-)Folder is accessible to the whole domain, including me and the user to run the task later.

the task ends on errorcode 0xc0000005 and no textfile has been written. What am i doing wrong? There is no textfile!

Thanks in Advance!

PS: the idea behind the task is to let it be run as a user who has access to network drive, so that data stored in the network drive can be accessible to the person on the pc, as connecting to a network drive is a pain.

Comment: you should always dispose, not just on an exception.

Comment: also this might swallow any exceptions that could happen.

Comment: What seems to be the issue? You didn't actually say what the problem is. What errors/exceptions are you getting?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener("C:\\temp\\test.txt"));
System.Diagnostics.Trace.AutoFlush = true;
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Something Something");` seems to work btw. why?

Comment: @ daniel: didnt copy and paste but write it here, ofc the dispose is in the finally block in real code. @oded: ill edit

Comment: What happens if you do this outside of the try{}?

Comment: Hi,

"Im using me (local admin, domain user) to implement and run the task in windows task scheduler". 

Have you considered writting an Windows NT service which performs this task for you? You can then install the NT Service using a specific user account (Security practice). NT Services are intended for execution without a user logged in.

Comment: @marvin: im stating in the postscriptum that the main use of the task is impersonification for access on a network device. im just using me to debug;-)

Comment: Shame on me.
My Temp-Folder is Read-Only... Problem solved :/ funny that system.diagnostics was able to write to it.

Comment: If your question is answered then mark it as such.

Comment: cannot answer my own questions - too new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error code of 5 indicates "Access Denied". Does the user that your scheduled task run under have permission to write to C:\TEMP?

Comment: thanks, this is the problem. but im still encountering (is that  a word?) problems, since the user is no local user and i dont want to share the folder... but its the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Always use using:

```
try {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test\test.txt", false)) {
        sw.WriteLine("Write something");
    }
}
catch (Exception e ) {
    DoSomeThing(e);
}
```

Comment: i guess writing using or try-finally doesnt affect the binaries. but thanks anyways;-) i know its a "recommended approach"